# Regular expression to get the main domain of a URL

Tags: php, regex

I have never used regex before and I was wondering how to write a regular expression in PHP that gets the domain of the URL. For example: 
http://www.hegnar.no/bors/article488276.ece --> hegnar.no

Comment: similar to this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891706/480021](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891706/480021)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `parse_url()` if you are specifically dealing with URLs.

For example:

```
$url = "http://www.hegnar.no/bors/article488276.ece";
$url_u_want = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

EDIT:
To take out the www. infront, use:

```
$url_u_want = preg_replace("/^www\./", "", $url_u_want);
```

Comment: That's perfect. It only doesn't remove the www. Any way to do that?

Comment: But what if it didn't have www. from the beginning, it won't work!

Comment: You want to strip off anything at the beginning before the first .? If you don't have www. That thing simply doesn't run and leave you with whatever you have, which is fine (i.e., you don't want to strip subdomain from subdomain.hegnar.no, correct?)

Comment: aha yeah got it ;)
I'll have to check first though before writing 
$url_u_want = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
or else I will destroy my link. right?

Comment: erh no, please test my solution first with different url and you'll see.

Answer (score 7):

You dont need to use regexp for this task.

Check PHP's built in function, parse_url
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: It returns null when the URL doesnt have www. or http

Comment: The function. Returns null if if the URL does not have www.

Comment: echo parse_url('http://www.google.com', PHP_URL_HOST);
==
www.google.com

then you can remove the www if you want with andreas's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
$page = "http://google.no/page/page_1.html";
preg_match_all("/((?:[a-z][a-z\\.\\d\\-]+)\\.(?:[a-z][a-z\\-]+))(?![\\w\\.])/", $page, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Can I remove the www. as well?

Comment: Yes, print_r(str_replace('www.', '', $result)); If the www. is found.

Answer (score 1):

See

[PHP Regex for extracting subdomains of arbitrary domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304527/php-regex-for-extracting-subdomains-of-arbitrary-domains/4304684#4304684)

and

[Javascript/Regex for finding just the root domain name without sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439863/javascript-regex-for-finding-just-the-root-domain-name-without-sub-domains/3765309#3765309)

Answer (score 1):

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$host = array_reverse(explode('.', $host));
$host = $host[1].'.'.$host[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem when you use parse_url, the $url with no .com or .net or etc then the result returned is [bannedadsense](http://bannedadsense.com), this mean returning true, the fact [bannedadsense](http://bannedadsense.com) is not a domain.

```
$url = 'http://bannedadsense/isbanned'; // this url will return false in preg_match
//$url = 'http://bannedadsense.com/isbanned'; // this url will return domain in preg_match
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
// return "bannedadsense", meaning this is right domain.
```

So that we need continue to check more a case with no dot extension (.com, .net, .org, etc)

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/i",$domain)) {
    echo $domain;
}else{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "false";
}
```